# Packages and Notebooks as a Databin

Tags: datadrop

The new [Data Drop](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/03/04/the-wolfram-data-drop-is-live/) product sounds interesting. Can I use `Databin` to share Packages and Notebooks?

If yes. How? Something like:

```
bin = CreateDatabin[]
DatabinAdd[bin, <|"myPack" -> "???"|>]
```

And then, how can I load a package stored in a `Databin`?

[cross related Wolfram Community question](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/452695)

Comment: You could store packages encoded (or not) as a String. Actually I think this is design oversight in Mathematica : a package is not a expression.

Answer (score 5):

An ancient question - I just started digging my nose into Databins.  Here's one way to store a package in databins.  the key is to drop them as inactivated expressions

```
Remove[Collatz]
Collatz[5]
bin = CreateDatabin[];
DatabinAdd[bin, 
 Import["ExampleData/Collatz.m", "InactivatedExpressions"]];
Collatz[5]
(* Collatz should remain unevaluated in both calls above *)
```

Now, to pull the package from the datadrop:

```
First@bin["Values"] // Activate
Collatz[5]
(* A string with some package information is generated here *)
(* {5, 16, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

I played briefly with [data semantics](http://www.wolfram.com/datadrop/quick-reference/data-semantics/) since `Package` is a valid [`$InterpreterType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$InterpreterTypes.html); however, I did not see any immediate benefit to my dummy code outside of requiring more text to parse the `Association`.

Comment: interesting. tks for sharing. +1